# How does OpenID delegation work on the Relying Party? Have the specs changed recently?

Tags: openid, specifications

Consider this scenario.
I have my own website, that I use as my identifier, but I use a third-party OpenID provider (in my case yahoo), as described [here](http://wiki2008.openid.net/Delegation), to login on Relying Party (RP) websites such stackoverflow and sourceforge.

It seemed to be a wise move:

- I am not locked in with an OpenID provider, since if/when yahoo will not offer the service anymore, or will start to charge for it, or I will not trust them anymore, I can switch provider painlessly
- I don't have the economic, administrative and security burden of installing and maintaining an OpenID provider on my server

**Question**

How is the RP supposed to work? My understanding is that it should use the identifier **I**  provide, and use the provider (yahoo) only for authentication (and not for identification). Is that correct? Did something change recently?
Just to be clear, I mean that my identification should be

http://www.mysite.com/myPreferredUrl

and not

https://me.yahoo.com/myYahooId (which is where my website "redirect" the authentication as described in the above website)

*Side note*

I'm asking this question also because things seems to be broken right now (they were ok few months ago). If I try to login on stackoverflow, I write the mysite.com URL, I am correctly "redirected" to the yahoo website, on which I log in, it asks me if I'd like to "continue on stackoverflow", I say yes, it "redirects" and on the stackoverflow site I see "This is an OpenID we haven't seen before", it shows my yahoo ID and I'm actually locked out!

Is it a bug, or am I missing something?

PS: if you are wondering how I'm writing this question, this is because on one of the many machines I use, a browser still has a valid cookie....

EDIT: Andrew Arnott's answer below suggested a way to fix my problem (i.e. switching to a different provider). But I'm still interested in some details: what has changed from OpenID 1.1 to 2.0, about delegation? Why in the specs it has been choosen to let the provider "break" the delegation? The more you explain, the better the chances to have your answer accepted.

Comment: The following links might shed some light, but I'm still interested in a more complete answer:
http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=607
http://openid.net/pipermail/general/2008-November/006468.html

Comment: added a bit to my answer, but that's all I can say.  I think your question should be refocused if my answer doesn't fairly answer what your question is.

Comment: Just another data-point. Blogger.com doesn't seem to work properly with delegation unless you include the openid2.provider and openid2.local_id link tags, in addition to the version 1 tags. Without the version 2 spec tags, it uses the provider's identifier not the one provided.

I don't know if this is Google's fault or something in the OpenID 2 spec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe Andrew's answer is quite accurate.  The only thing I can add is a little bit about how the v2.0 spec ended up the way it did, allowing the provider to choose to not work with delegation.  I think one of the motivators was the server-directed identity selection, in which the user just supplies "yahoo.com" (or click the Yahoo button), and then their chosen ID comes back from the server in the id_res response.  This also allows the server to do things like offer a choice of which ID to send (as Yahoo does) or send a unique identifier to each RP (as Google does).

It also means that all the necessary information is in an `id_res` response, which means the RP doesn't need to store state from its `checkid` request in order to process the response.  In fact, a provider could send an `id_res` response directly to the RP without the RP initiating it with a `checkid` request at all.

A v1.x provider was completely unaware when delegation was evening happening.  This design prevented a provider from even choosing to not support delegation, but also made for some UI problems; it would be asking if you wanted to provide the "joe.coolprovider.com" ID when you were actually using your delegated "joesmith.org" ID.

So, there's the tradeoff.  Delegation is still possible, so the hope was that users who really want delegation (which, let's face it, is going to be dwarfed by the number of users from these big sites) can choose providers that offer the features they need.  (In other words, let the market fight it out.)

Comment: Thanks, those are the details I wanted to know. I personally think everybody should really use delegation from a domain they control, instead of just relying on a "big site" which might change its decision and let the user lose not just a single account there, but every other account (s)he created everywhere. Well, that's another story, though.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think Yahoo supports OpenID delegation.  That is, StackOverflow and other RPs may perform discovery on your own identifier and set up the delegation auth request correctly, but Yahoo might be choosing (arguably contrary to the spec) to send an identity assertion for their own identifier rather than the one given by the RP.

The specs haven't changed from OpenID 1.1 to 2.0.  The specs do not suggest or endorse Yahoo!'s behavior, and only Yahoo can authoritatively comment on their reasoning.

StackOverflow delegation still works.  Yahoo broke you, it seems.  I suggest you leverage what the delegation bought you by changing who you delegate authentication to.  www.myopenid.com for example supports delegation.  If you change your own identifier to point to that, you should be able to get back into StackOverflow as your old self again. :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try that and report here if it works. But please elaborate on what the RP (and the provider, I thought it was just the RP) should do, to properly support delegation. I wasn't able to find enough information online.

Comment: The RP should send an authentication request with openid.claimed_id set to the discovered identifier (the one you control) and openid.identity set to the one you're delegating to (your Yahoo! assigned OpenID).  
The OP SHOULD keep the openid.claimed_id the same (except in the directed identity case which this is not) and require that the user specified in the openid.identity be the one who is logged into Yahoo before sending the assertion.

Comment: Yes, it turned out that MyOpenID works. I'm upvoting your question, but not marking it as accepted since I'd like to see more details.